# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded with setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I came across this code to highlight in JavaScript. When I desected and ran on my own machine, and not jsFiddle I got the following error.

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/bZb7V/

To get around this, I looked at the other questions on StackOverflow and added in a setTimeout() function, but I still get the error. How come?

```
function getSelection() 
{
    var seltxt = '';

     if (window.getSelection) 
     { 
         seltxt = setTimeout(window.getSelection(), 5000); 
     } 
     else if (document.getSelection) 
     { 
         seltxt = setTimeout(document.getSelection(), 5000); 
     } 
     else if (document.selection) 
     { 
         seltxt = setTimeout(document.selection.createRange().text, 5000); 
     }
    else return;

    return seltxt;
}
```

Comment: You have to pass a function to setTimeout, not its result: `setTimeout(function)`, not `setTimeout(function())`

Comment: @georg I have tried this, but it still throws the same error

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a reference to the function to the setTimeout function. You are calling the function directly, should be as follows:
function getSelection() 
{
    var seltxt = '';

```
 if (window.getSelection) 
 { 
     seltxt = setTimeout(window.getSelection, 5000); 
 } 
 else if (document.getSelection) 
 { 
     seltxt = setTimeout(document.getSelection, 5000); 
 } 
 else if (document.selection) 
 { 
     seltxt = setTimeout(document.selection.createRange, 5000); 
 }
else return;

return seltxt;
}
```

Not sure about the last one since you are calling .text after the function call.

Comment: i have tried this, it doesn't work unfortunatly and causes the same error